Prestashop, add field to admin cms page form
I want to add option to add contact form to specific pages,
I have the hooks: actionAdminCmsFormModifier and actionAdminCmsControllerSaveBefore
My functions are not printing anything, I've already tried changing hook names but it does not print my var_dumps and echo's
public function hookDisplayCmsPage($params){
    echo "HERE";
    $cms = $this->context->smarty->getTemplateVars('cms');
    if ($cms && isset($cms['id_cms']) && $this->isContactFormEnabled($cms['id_cms'])) {
        $contactform_module = Module::getInstanceByName('contactform');

        return $contactform_module->hookDisplayContactForm($params);
    }
    return '';
}

and backoffice:

public function hookActionAdminCmsFormModifier($params)
{
    error_log('hookActionAdminCmsFormModifier called'); // Log to error log
    var_dump($params);
    echo "HEREEEEE";
    
    $cms = $params['object'];
    $enable_contact_form = (bool) Configuration::get('CMS_CONTACTFORM_' . $cms->id);
    
    $params['fields']['content']['form']['input'][] = [
        'type' => 'switch',
        'label' => $this->l('Enable Contact Form'),
        'name' => 'enable_contact_form',
        'values' => [
            [
                'id' => 'enable_contact_form_on',
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => $this->l('Ativado') // Ensure correct translation
            ],
            [
                'id' => 'enable_contact_form_off',
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => $this->l('Desativado') // Ensure correct translation
            ]
        ],
        'is_bool' => true,
        'desc' => $this->l('Ativar o formulário de contacto nesta página.'),
        'value' => $enable_contact_form
    ];
    $params['fields_value']['enable_contact_form'] = $enable_contact_form;
    return $params;
}

None of the echos prints.
Update:
I added {hook h='displayCmsPage'} on page.tpl under theme folder, the function executes on front office, but I wanted to place the hook inside one of the blocks, but it seems to get replaced inside those blocks. How can one work with prestashop without having to modify TPL files? Shouldn't I be able to use a existing hook? If so which hook is to use when presenting CMS pages?
Am I the only one working with prestashop? Seems like there's little community around this CMS.
I'm new to prestashop, I don't quite fully understand the dynamics of symphony on the matter of adding fields on forms, and add content to tpl files
